# Images disappearance while using WordPress, tutor theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, custom-wordpress-pages

My images got disappearance when I didn't delete them, while using WordPress Tutor Theme, and page builder. #Wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Check your browser's devtools. Your images might be referenced incorrectly. So there may be a chance that you'll need to readd them so that they're correctly referenced.

It would be helpful as well to post a link. That'll help us give you accurate help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).